# unable to upgrade from 12.10 to newer ver.

Tags: do-release-upgrade

im having extreme issues being unable to upgrade and force upgrade keeps telling me to check repositories, i want to install a newer ver. but unable to do much of anything. what is the proper steps and can some one walk me through it?

Answer (score 2):

Short answer, you can't do that much of a jump in releases.
Backup what you need and do a fresh install, it's a lot easier.